Mutual TLS connection from OpenLiberty with custom keystore
I'm trying to use configured host-specific outbound SSL configuration in OpenLiberty to make an https connection to a remote system (Apple Pay, in this case, but I don't think relevant).
I know the keystore and password and protocols are correct, because when I do it entirely programmatically, like shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63080443/796761, the connection and request fully work.
However, when I remove all the keystore/SSL setup and try to fall back on what I've configured in server.xml, I get the same error as I get when I'm not setting up SSL at all. (Which, in this case is java.io.IOException: HTTP/1.1 header parser received no bytes.)
Relevant server.xml elements:
    <featureManager>
        <feature>webProfile-8.0</feature> <!-- adds ssl-1.0 -->
...
    </featureManager>

...
    <keyStore id="applePayKeyStore" location="c:/keys/MerchID.AZMVDNOW.p12" password="redacted"/>

    <ssl id="applePaySSL" keyStoreRef="applePayKeyStore" clientAuthentication="true" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2">
        <outboundConnection host="apple-pay-gateway-cert.apple.com"/>
    </ssl>

Java code:
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(validationEndpoint)
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .POST(BodyPublishers.ofString(jsonRequest))
            .build();
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();

        return client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString()).body();

Where validationEndpoint is set to https://apple-pay-gateway-cert.apple.com/paymentservices/paymentSession
Again, if I instead replace the above client with the following, the request succeeds:
        char[] passwordChars = keystorePassword.toCharArray();

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("/keys/MerchID.AZMVDNOW.p12"), passwordChars);

        KeyManagerFactory keyMgrFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        keyMgrFactory.init(keyStore, passwordChars);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sslContext.init(keyMgrFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

        SSLParameters sslParam = new SSLParameters();
        sslParam.setNeedClientAuth(true);

        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .sslContext(sslContext)
            .sslParameters(sslParam).build();

OpenLiberty 24.0.0.6, JDK 17
So, the question is how can I get Liberty to use this specific keystore when making an https connection to the specified server?
I haven't so far found an example of making such a connection with Liberty automatically using the configured SSL configuration, so I hope I'm just missing some simple glue.
Edit:
javax.net.debug=ssl doesn't tell me anything helpful:
[err] javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|69|HttpClient-1-Worker-0|2024-07-12 20:30:31.041 UTC|SSLCipher.java:1870|KeyLimit read side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
[err] javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|69|HttpClient-1-Worker-0|2024-07-12 20:30:31.041 UTC|SSLCipher.java:2024|KeyLimit write side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
[err] javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|69|HttpClient-1-Worker-0|2024-07-12 20:30:31.051 UTC|SSLCipher.java:1870|KeyLimit read side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
[err] javax.net.ssl|ALL|69|HttpClient-1-Worker-0|2024-07-12 20:30:31.053 UTC|X509Authentication.java:223|No X.509 cert selected for [RSA, EC]

[err] javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|69|HttpClient-1-Worker-0|2024-07-12 20:30:31.053 UTC|SSLCipher.java:2024|KeyLimit write side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
[err] javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|91|Finalizer thread|2024-07-12 20:30:31.127 UTC|SSLSocketImpl.java:577|duplex close of SSLSocket

[err] javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|91|Finalizer thread|2024-07-12 20:30:31.129 UTC|SSLSocketImpl.java:1785|close the SSL connection (passive)

Edit 2:
With Liberty SSL tracing, it looks like the relevant objects loaded up successfully, including this entry showing that Liberty was able to see the certificate in the store:

[7/12/24, 20:49:04:920 UTC] 00000031 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.WSKeyStore                             3 alias: apple pay merchant identity certificate

And mapped the host name to the configuration:

[7/12/24, 20:49:05:241 UTC] 00000031 id=00000000
com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLChannelProvider           3
setSslConfig
id=applePaySSL
{com.ibm.ws.ssl.internal.RepertoireConfigService,
com.ibm.wsspi.ssl.SSLConfiguration}={verifyHostname=false,
service.scope=bundle,
component.name=com.ibm.ws.ssl.internal.RepertoireConfigService,
TrustStore.target=(service.pid=com.ibm.ws.ssl.keystore_0),
trustDefaultCerts=false,
KeyStore.target=(service.pid=com.ibm.ws.ssl.keystore_0),
sslProtocol=TLSv1.2, config.source=file,
outboundConnection.0.host=apple-pay-gateway-cert.apple.com,
id=applePaySSL, service.pid=com.ibm.ws.ssl.repertoire_0,
clientAuthenticationSupported=false, service.id=621,
keyStoreRef=com.ibm.ws.ssl.keystore_0, enforceCipherOrder=false,
service.bundleid=132,
outboundConnection.0.config.referenceType=com.ibm.ws.ssl.repertoire.config.outboundConnection,
osgi.ds.satisfying.condition.target=(osgi.condition.id=true),
config.overrides=true, clientAuthentication=true, component.id=487,
effectiveTrustStore=com.ibm.ws.ssl.keystore_0,
config.id=com.ibm.ws.ssl.repertoire[applePaySSL], securityLevel=HIGH,
service.factoryPid=com.ibm.ws.ssl.repertoire, service.vendor=IBM,
config.displayId=ssl[applePaySSL]}

But I think the outbound connection used the defaultSSLConfig instead of the applePaySSL one:

[7/12/24, 20:50:43:868 UTC] 00000046 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.ssl.SSLPropertyUtils                              > lookupProperties alias=defaultSSLConfig Entry
[7/12/24, 20:50:43:868 UTC] 00000046 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.ssl.SSLPropertyUtils                              > getProperties sslAliasName=defaultSSLConfig
currentConnectionInfo={com.ibm.ssl.direction=outbound}

I can't paste the entire huge trace here, but can provide specifics if needed.
Edit 3
On OutboundSSLSelections:
[7/15/24, 20:29:11:882 UTC] 00000031 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.OutboundSSLSelections                  3 loadOutboundConnectionInfo 
                                                                                                               Adding apple-pay-gateway-cert.apple.com,* to the host list

From a later test just now, I do see these when looking up other host names:
[7/17/24, 12:40:30:595 UTC] 0000003b id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.OutboundSSLSelections                  3 SSLConfig dynamic selection info: apple-pay-gateway-cert.apple.com,*
[7/17/24, 12:40:30:595 UTC] 0000003b id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.OutboundSSLSelections                  3 This entry has 2 attributes.
[7/17/24, 12:40:30:595 UTC] 0000003b id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.OutboundSSLSelections                  3 Host: apple-pay-gateway-cert.apple.com, Port: *
[7/17/24, 12:40:30:595 UTC] 0000003b id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.OutboundSSLSelections                  3 Host does not match.
[7/17/24, 12:40:30:595 UTC] 0000003b id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.OutboundSSLSelections                  3 No match found list
[7/17/24, 12:40:30:595 UTC] 0000003b id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.OutboundSSLSelections                  < lookForMatchInList Exit 
[7/17/24, 12:40:30:595 UTC] 0000003b id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.OutboundSSLSelections                  3 Cache miss tree set size is 2 entries.
[7/17/24, 12:40:30:595 UTC] 0000003b id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.OutboundSSLSelections                  3 No match found in host or host and port list.
[7/17/24, 12:40:30:595 UTC] 0000003b id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.OutboundSSLSelections                  < getPropertiesFromDynamicSelectionInfo Exit 

But no entries at all for com.ibm.ssl.remoteHost with the apple host.

Add -Djavax.net.debug=ssl to your JVM's system properties before doing any SSL connections, either via command-line option or some other means.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71563289/how-can-i-get-debug-messages-from-javas-ssl-handshake

@AndrewHenle: since approx. 2018 javax.net.debug=ssl is not sufficient for useful JSSE logging; you must add subcategories and for this case I suggest javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:keymanager. (I'm not sure it will help when the explicitly-coded JSSE setup does work, but it's worth a try.)

Wow, what am I missing on the close vote and down vote? I thought I provided a lot of investigation.

"more focus, asking more than one question". I don't think so, but I'll spell out more clearly...

Based on previous answers and comments, I confirm that this works, but with a dependence on WebSphere-specific classes:
        SSLContext sslContext =
            JSSEHelper.getInstance().getSSLContext("applePaySSL", null, null);

        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .sslContext(sslContext).build();

(Where I also had to add trustDefaultCerts="true" to the <ssl id="applePaySSL" > element shown above in server.xml.)
To remove that dependence from the Java code, I looked for a way to inject the generic SSLContext instance instead. Here's what worked for our Spring DI XML configuration:
    <bean id="libertyJSSEHelper" class="com.ibm.websphere.ssl.JSSEHelper" factory-method="getInstance"/>

    <bean id="appleSSLContext" factory-bean="libertyJSSEHelper" factory-method="getSSLContext">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="applePaySSL"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1"><null/></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="2"><null/></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

Reducing the above code to
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .sslContext(this.getSslContext()).build();


Try explicitly loading transportSecurity-1.0, then if still wrong try:
final Map<String,Object> map = Map.of(
     "com.ibm.ssl.remoteHost", "apple-pay-gateway-cert.apple.com",
     "com.ibm.ssl.remotePort", "443",
     "com.ibm.ssl.direction", "outbound");

JSSEHelper helper = JSSEHelper.getInstance();
SSLContext sslctx = helper.getSSLContext(null, map, null);
...
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().sslContext(sslctx).build();

Or with jaxrs client:
Properties p =  JSSEHelper.getInstance().getProperties(null, map, null);
ClientBuilder builder = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().property("com.ibm.ws.jaxrs.client.ssl.config", p.getProperty(Constants.SSLPROP_ALIAS));


Ok, explicitly adding transportSecurity doesn't seem to have made a difference, but using the explicit Map and objects (with the feature removed again) does. (With that setup, I get a trust issue with the server cert - which I don't get with my code.) But what might that behavior tell us? (And, of course, I definitely don't want to have to code in com.ibm implementation properties)

In my testing, I wasn't looking at the client cert aspect, but at the trust aspect for pass/fail.  Do you need a custom keyStore w/ the right CA to act as a trustStore in that outbound SSL config?

surprisingly, using the JSSEHelper API to get dynamic outbound for both HttpClient and the jaxrs client looks required in my testing

other trivia I learned, with ssl-1.0 I saw no relevant trace but did have isTransportSecurityEnabled false which masks all of the outbound stuff.

I don't know if my working code also "trusts" because it uses the keystore for trust as well, or like because it's falling back on cacerts. Or why that would be different from the code you provided. I think I could get the trust issue resolved, but honestly, my code seems more straightforward. If I could manage this entirely through Liberty config, that would be my first choice. I think we were able to do this kind of thing as expected with tWAS, and it sure looks to me like it's intended to be possible with the Liberty options.

I did some re-testing and transportSecurity-1.0 was enough for httpclient but not the jaxrs client.

you're saying that with your testing, using the default HttpClient without any of the custom code worked once you added transportSecurity-1.0 ? It did not for me, so I wonder what's different.

there is some recent discussion of a regression in this area since 24.0.0.3.
I also spent some more time on my tests, and both cases do require custom code for me. OTOH, the report of the regression implies it worked at 24.0.0.2 and earlier and then broke. https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/29124

https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/29124 only applies to the JAX-RS Client and not HttpClient.
Additionally, I don't expect dynamic outbound to work if you don't use JSSEHelper to get Liberty's SSLContext in either case.

@atanders somehow I hadn't seen your comment, but sure enough, 24.0.0.9 didn't address this. Perhaps you can add an answer with details on how to make this work with the minimum code required? (Although I still don't see what the point of dynamic outbound SSL configuration is if it can't handle this case. And I really thought it did under tWAS.)

I recently struggled with a similar issue.
Below is a sample trace snippet from the Liberty code. It shows the process of matching the hostname and port from an outbound connection request with those configured in the server.xml.
In my case, the trace indicated that the request came in with a hostname, while the server.xml was configured with an IP address for the host. I hope you find a similar snippet that can shed some light on your issue
[06/06/24 11:41:38:461 EDT] 00000037 OutboundSSLSe 3   SSLConfig dynamic selection info: 192.168.252.10,123     
[06/06/24 11:41:38:461 EDT] 00000037 OutboundSSLSe 3   This entry has 2 attributes.     
[06/06/24 11:41:38:461 EDT] 00000037 OutboundSSLSe 3   Host: 192.168.252.10, Port: 123 
[06/06/24 11:41:38:461 EDT] 00000037 OutboundSSLSe 3   Host does not match.


Interesting, I don't see lines like that at all. Adding up above what I do see ...

Thank you so much for posting the trace snippet.  The snippet shows "apple-pay-gateway-cert.apple.com" is in the configuration and the input hostname does not match.  Now I am dying to know what the input hostname is. When you get a chance, kindly share the earlier trace.  In my previous case, I was expecting ip address to be passed in. To my surprise, the application converted the ip address to its hostname.

Sorry I wasn't clear, but the excerpt I showed was for a different lookup, not the apple one. Just to show that while doing lookups, it does see the apple one in the list.
